# How to select a row based on a timestamp in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am struggling to retrieve a particular row based on its exact timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.ERIC( SOME_ROW_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL
                        , MY_TIMESTAMP  TIMESTAMP_NTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))
                        );
```

I insert a row in there

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ERIC(SOME_ROW_ID) VALUES(1);
```

I retrieve it...

```
SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.ERIC;
```

This returns a value like this: "2020-04-07 09:58:51"

Now, if I try to retrieve that row, I keep missing it

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PUBLIC.ERIC
  WHERE MY_TIMESTAMP = CAST('2020-04-07 09:58:51' AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9));
```

How am I supposed to retrieve that row?
I suppose I am getting mixed up in the timestamp thing (or precision)...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timestamp_ntz(9)` has nanosecond precision, so your where clause needs to also have nanosecond precision (e.g. `2020-04-07 10:34:04.426`)